# How to use AllocateAndInitializeSid for an AD group?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, active-directory

I'd like to create a SID for domain Administrators group and pass it to `CheckTokenMembership` in order to determine if a given AD user belongs to the group.  However, I'm not quite sure what identifier authority and sub-authorities should be used with `AllocateAndInitializeSid`.  All 'working' examples that I've seen so far deal with local groups only.

Example:

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY ntAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID adminGroup;

AllocateAndInitializeSid(&ntAuthority,
                         2,
                         SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
                         DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                         &adminGroup);
```

What authority and sub-authorities should be used to create a SID for AD Administrators group?  I tried `DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_ADMINS` and `DOMAIN_USER_RID_ADMIN` with `SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY` but `CheckTokenMembership` always reported that a given user was not a member of the group which was not correct.

Any examples and pointers to on-line docs would be appreciated.

Comment: but which token you use for check ? admin under uac ? he have `S-1-5-32-544` (sid which you use) with `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` attribute

Comment: I use a token obtained from LogonUser. Example: LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PRIVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken)

Comment: but user is not elevated I guess ? in this case `S-1-5-32-544` (sid which you use) with `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` attribute in token. and CheckTokenMembership  and must return false

Comment: Which user should be elevated?  Should it be the user under which process calling LogonUser runs?  Also, how do I find out if SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY attribute is present in the token?

Comment: @RbMm, don't confuse local machine administrators and domain administrators group. UAC has no effect on domain group membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LsaQueryInformationPolicy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `PolicyDnsDomainInformation` to retrieve the SID for the computer's primary domain.

Alternatively, if you know that the account you are querying belongs to the same domain as the domain administrators group you're interested in, you can use [GetWindowsAccountDomainSid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446676(v=vs.85).aspx) to extract the domain SID from the account SID.

Once you've got the domain SID, you can use [CreateWellKnownSid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446585(v=vs.85).aspx) to create the SID for the Domain Admins group.  Use the `WinAccountDomainAdminsSid` option.  Then it is just a matter of calling CheckTokenMembership() as you already suggested.

Comment: I have no problems with getting a specific domain SID.  How can I use it to determine if a given domain user belongs to domain admin group?

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Comment: CreateWellKnownSid() / CheckTokenMembership() works for me so I'm accepting this answer.  RbMm's suggestion also works but this approach works better for me because I keep domain SID around.

Answer (score 0):

you can enumerate token groups and check are interesting for you `SID` present.

```
volatile UCHAR guz;

ULONG IsDomainAdmin(HANDLE hToken, PBOOL IsMember)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x100, err;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PTOKEN_GROUPS ptg;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenGroups, buf, cb, &rcb))
        {
            *IsMember = FALSE;

            if (ULONG GroupCount = ptg->GroupCount)
            {
                PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Groups = ptg->Groups;
                do 
                {
                    // S-1-5-21-domain-512
                    PSID Sid = Groups++->Sid;
                    PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY psia = GetSidIdentifierAuthority(Sid);

                    static SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY ntAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

                    if (!memcmp(psia, &ntAuthority, sizeof(SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY)))
                    {
                        ULONG n = *GetSidSubAuthorityCount(Sid);

                        if (
                            1 < n &&
                            *GetSidSubAuthority(Sid, 0) == SECURITY_NT_NON_UNIQUE &&
                            *GetSidSubAuthority(Sid, n - 1) == DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_ADMINS
                            )
                        {
                            *IsMember = TRUE;

                            return NOERROR;
                        }
                    }

                } while (--GroupCount);
            }
            return NOERROR;
        }

    } while ((err = GetLastError()) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

    return err;
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong in most cases and CheckTokenMembership should be used. It is very rare to treat a deny-only SID as a "valid" group entry.

Comment: @Anders - easy can be add here check for SID attributes (are `SE_GROUP_ENABLED` exist and `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` not exist) but I not sure how need interpret this case - we want check *access* or *membership* ? and `wrong in most cases` - what you mean under this ? that `DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_ADMINS` not enabled in token in most case ? you not confuse it with `DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS` ?

Comment: For "most cases" I'm mostly worried about people finding this code and using it without understanding that there is a deny attribute. The lines between access and membership can be a bit blurry and if the deny bit is set, who set it and why? Intentionally restricting yourself or company policy? There are even more security considerations. I'm not sure if a local admin would be able to create a token with a deny SID for a group they are not a member of. The win32 functions are supposed to prevent you from doing that but I'm not sure about Nt* APIs or a kernel driver.

Comment: @Anders - when I write this I also have doubt - use or not use SID attributes. check *access* or *membership*. from [CreateRestrictedToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446583(v=vs.85).aspx) - `The function ignores any SIDs in the SidsToDisable array that are not also found in the existing token.` Nt* functions here not change picture. but possible of course create token from zero by using `ZwCreateToken`, but for this need have privileges

Comment: so to speak - if user have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` (all local admins by default settings) - he can got and `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` and after this create *any* token from zero. if user can run own kernel mode code - it also can do this. so can create token with any sid and attributes, and how this case ?

Comment: And this brings us back to the real question, why does the OP want to know if a user is a member. And since we currently don't know why, the only sane thing to do is to use the provided API function instead of rolling your own (IMHO). If Microsoft adds a another flag then the code would still be correct. Your current code follows the NT4 spec, the deny flag was added in 2000.